# Something went wrong page after after pressing on DeleteButton

Tags: react-admin, admin-on-rest

Everytime I click on a delete button in a List component, the page shows this error page.
The deletion works though.

[The error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xas8W.png)

```html
export const MaterialList = props => (
    <List {...props}>
        <Datagrid rowClick="edit">
            <NumberField source="REGEL_ID" />
            <DateField source="STAND" />
            <NumberField source="MaterialID" />
            <NumberField source="DruckstufenID" />
            <TextField source="Bezeichnung" />
            <TextField source="Bezeichnung2" />
            <TextField source="pA_Artikel" />
            <TextField source="Menge" />
            <NumberField source="DefaultHaken" />
            <NumberField source="Verdichten" />
            <TextField source="pA_Artikel_Original" />
            <EditButton />
            <DeleteButton />
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
);
```

Is there someone who atleast understands the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We noticed this bug a few days ago and it has been fixed in v3.3.3.

Comment: yup, upgraded the version and it works again, thanks for the info!